# Running Hive Queries using python client in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hive

I am using ipython on Windows 10. I wanted to run hive queries through this and I am facing problems in this.

I tried using,

```
import pyhs2
connection = hive.connect(host='xx.xx.xxx.xx', port= 22, authMechanism='LDAP', user='username', password='password')
```

But I am getting,

```
TTransportException: Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2
```

On Searching more about this,I got the following link.

https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/32

Also I tried to install hive_utils package,

```
pip install hive_utils
```

But I am getting the following error while installing,

```
"path '%s' cannot end with '/'" % pathname
    ValueError: path 'src/' cannot end with '/'

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

when I search more about this I got this link,

https://github.com/eventbrite/python_hive_utils/issues/1

Is there a way I can run hive queries in ipython using windows? Can anybody help me in solving this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any resolution for your error -- @haimen ?